# How do I correct this AssertionError in my unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertion

I'm working on an arithmetic arranger problem.

The program arranges and returns the problem as shown below in the console output. It is a function that accepts two parameters: a list where each item is an addition or subtraction problem, and an optional second argument that, when true, displays each answer beneath the dashes under each problem.

To me, it looks like the program is failing 1 out of the 6 tests in the test_module file.

Here's the console output when I run the program, the error is shown here:

```
 python main.py
   32      3801      50      123        12
+ 698    -    2    + 50    -  49    + 3600
-----    ------    ----    -----    ------
  730      3799     100       74      3612
F.....
======================================================================
FAIL: test_arrangement (test_module.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/boilerplate-arithmetic-formatter-4/test_module.py", line 10, in test_arrangement
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected different output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with ["3 + 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]')
AssertionError: '    [36 chars]   -    2    + 43    +  49\n-----    ------    ----    -----\n' != '    [36 chars]   -    2    + 43    +  49\n-----    ------    ----    -----'
      3      3801      45      123
  + 855    -    2    + 43    +  49
- -----    ------    ----    -----
?                                 -
+ -----    ------    ----    ----- : Expected different output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with ["3 + 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Here are the contents of my main.py file:

```
from arithmetic_arranger import arithmetic_arranger
from unittest import main


print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "50 + 50", "123 - 49", "12 + 3600"], True))


# Run unit tests automatically
main(module='test_module', exit=False)
```

Here are the contents of my arithmetic_arranger file:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, results):
  if len(problems) > 5:
    return 'Error: Too many problems.'
  
  top = []
  bottom = []
  dashes = []
  spaces = '    '
  answers = []

# ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "50 + 50", "123 - 49", "12 + 3600"]

  for problem in problems:
    first = '  ' + problem.split()[0]
    second = problem.split(' ', 1)[1]
    length_first = len(first)
    length_second = len(second)
    difference_first = length_first - length_second
    difference_second = length_second - length_first

    width_first = len(problem.split()[0])
    width_second = len(problem.split()[2])

    if width_first > 4 or width_second > 4:
      return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."
      
    if second[0] != '+' and second[0] != '-':
      return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."
    
    if first.lstrip().isdigit() != True or second[2:].isdigit() != True:
      return 'Error: Numbers must only contain digits.'
    
    if difference_first > 0:
      second = second[0] + ' ' * (difference_first + 1) + second[2:]
    elif difference_second > 0:
      first = ' ' * difference_second + first

    # Optional condition to display answers under problems:
    if results:
      if second[0] == '+':
        answer = int(first) + int(second[2:])
      else:
        answer = int(first) - int(second[2:])

      answer_to_string = str(answer)
      length_result = len(answer_to_string)
      answer_to_string = '  ' + answer_to_string
      length_maximum = max([len(first.lstrip()), len(second[1:].lstrip())])

      if length_maximum > length_result:
        answer_to_string = ' ' * (length_maximum - length_result) + answer_to_string
      elif length_maximum < length_result:
        answer_to_string = answer_to_string[1:]

      answers.append(answer_to_string)

  # Append variables to lists
    top.append(first)
    bottom.append(second)
    dashes.append('-' * len(second))

  # Set spacing
    spaced_top = spaces.join(top)
    spaced_bottom = spaces.join(bottom)
    spaced_dashes = spaces.join(dashes)
    spaced_answers = spaces.join(answers)
  
  return spaced_top + '\n' + spaced_bottom + '\n' + spaced_dashes + '\n' + spaced_answers
```

Here are the contents of my test_module.py file:

```
import unittest
from arithmetic_arranger import arithmetic_arranger


# the test case
class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_arrangement(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["3 + 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], False)
        expected = "    3      3801      45      123\n+ 855    -    2    + 43    +  49\n-----    ------    ----    -----"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected different output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with ["3 + 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]')

        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["11 + 4", "3801 - 2999", "1 + 2", "123 + 49", "1 - 9380"], False)
        expected = "  11      3801      1      123         1\n+  4    - 2999    + 2    +  49    - 9380\n----    ------    ---    -----    ------"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected different output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with ["11 + 4", "3801 - 2999", "1 + 2", "123 + 49", "1 - 9380"]')

    def test_too_many_problems(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["44 + 815", "909 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49", "888 + 40", "653 + 87"], True)
        expected = "Error: Too many problems."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with more than five problems to return "Error: Too many problems."')

    def test_incorrect_operator(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["3 / 855", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True)
        expected = "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, '''Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with a problem that uses the "/" operator to return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."''')
        
    def test_too_many_digits(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["24 + 85215", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True)
        expected = "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with a problem that has a number over 4 digits long to return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."')

    def test_only_digits(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["98 + 3g5", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True)
        expected = "Error: Numbers must only contain digits."
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with a problem that contains a letter character in the number to return "Error: Numbers must only contain digits."')

    def test_solutions(self):
        actual = arithmetic_arranger(["32 - 698", "1 - 3801", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True)
        expected = "   32         1      45      123\n- 698    - 3801    + 43    +  49\n-----    ------    ----    -----\n -666     -3800      88      172"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected solutions to be correctly displayed in output when calling "arithmetic_arranger()" with arithmetic problems and a second argument of `True`.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: [Repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372404/what-does-this-assertionerror-mean-in-the-context-of-my-code-fail-test-arrange)
Changing a single argument in your code doesn't warrant posting a separate question that is nearly identical. You can edit the original post, add comments to the question, or add comments to answers, as you did, then allow time for follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too much into it, it looks like you are adding a newline at the end in the arithmetic_arranger function even if the result should not be printed:

```
return spaced_top + '\n' + spaced_bottom + '\n' + spaced_dashes + '\n' + spaced_answers
```

That newline is not present in the testcases.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working so I'm posting the final code from the arithmetic_arranger file here:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, results = False):
  if len(problems) > 5:
    return 'Error: Too many problems.'
  
  top = []
  bottom = []
  dashes = []
  spaces = '    '
  answers = []

# ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "50 + 50", "123 - 49", "12 + 3600"]

  for problem in problems:
    first = '  ' + problem.split()[0]
    second = problem.split(' ', 1)[1]
    difference_first = len(first) - len(second)
    difference_second = len(second) - len(first)

    width_first = len(problem.split()[0])
    width_second = len(problem.split()[2])

    if width_first > 4 or width_second > 4:
      return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."
      
    if second[0] != '+' and second[0] != '-':
      return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."
    
    if first.lstrip().isdigit() != True or second[2:].isdigit() != True:
      return 'Error: Numbers must only contain digits.'
    
    if difference_first > 0:
      second = second[0] + ' ' * (difference_first + 1) + second[2:]
    elif difference_second > 0:
      first = ' ' * difference_second + first

    # Optional condition to display answers under problems:
    if results:
      if second[0] == '+':
        answer = int(first) + int(second[2:])
      else:
        answer = int(first) - int(second[2:])

      answer_to_string = str(answer)
      length_result = len(answer_to_string)
      answer_to_string = '  ' + answer_to_string
      length_maximum = max([len(first.lstrip()), len(second[1:].lstrip())])

      if length_maximum > length_result:
        answer_to_string = ' ' * (length_maximum - length_result) + answer_to_string
      elif length_maximum < length_result:
        answer_to_string = answer_to_string[1:]

      answers.append(answer_to_string)

  # Append variables to lists
    top.append(first)
    bottom.append(second)
    dashes.append('-' * len(second))

  # Set spacing
    spaced_top = spaces.join(top)
    spaced_bottom = spaces.join(bottom)
    spaced_dashes = spaces.join(dashes)
    spaced_answers = spaces.join(answers)
  
  if results:
    arranged_problems = spaced_top + '\n' + spaced_bottom + '\n' + spaced_dashes + '\n' + spaced_answers
  else:
    arranged_problems = spaced_top + '\n' + spaced_bottom + '\n' + spaced_dashes

  return arranged_problems
```